# JQL - How to filter linked issues by type?

Tags: jira, jql, automation-for-jira

I'm implementing Automation for Jira for my current project, but have hit a roadblock. Currently the workflow is like this:

- Trigger -> Issue transitioned to Resolved
- Condition -> Issue type
  equals "Test Run"
- Condition -> Issue matches issueLinkType (created)
- Action -> Send Slack message

I would want to add a condition to the workflow that the action is only done if the condition says that the linked issues that are created are either Bug or Performance. Currently the message prints out all types of linked issues (like Stories, other Test Runs etc) and that is not what I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using JQL?

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, or for the next person... try this JQL

```
linkedIssue IN linkedIssues("{{issue.key}}") and issuetype in (Bug, Performance)
```